# Technique for when Hessian matrix's determinant is zero

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, determinant, hessian-matrix

In order to find the nature of critical points of this function

$$f(x, y, z) = xy + xz + yz -x +z$$

Solving de system of equations given by $\nabla f = 0$ I end up with the point $(-1, 0, 1)$. If the function has a maximum, minimum or settle point, it will be at this point.

For the Hessian matrix I found the determinant is $0$:

$$\det(H_f) = \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

So I conclude nothing on the nature of that critical point. Where do I go from here? What techniques could I usually go for when I'm caught up in this inconclusive test?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant is $2$, not $0$. Actually, the eigenvalues are $2$ (once) and $-1$ (twice). In particular, the point is a saddle point.

Comment: Oh, my. Thank you professor. I can’t believe it I was doing the artithemtic wrong

Comment: How is it obvious that it's a saddle point? I found the eigenvalues and I got the characteristic equation $- \lambda ^3 +3\lambda + 2 = 0$. From here how do I know that it has solutions where $\lambda_1 > 0$ and $\lambda_2 < 0$?

Comment: The determinant is $2$, which is greater than $0$. Since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, it follows that either the matrix has three eigenvalues greater than $0$, or one eigenvalue greater than $0$ and two eigenvalues smaller than $0$. But the trace is $0$, and the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues. So, the matrix cannot have three eigenvalues greater than $0$.